# jquery .animate() nao anima meu div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Bom, estou tentando fazer algo supostamente básico usando o .animate() do Jquery, mas não consigo que ele anime o div, mesmo selecionando corretamente o elemento do html com o "$()". 
Aqui esta o JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/sn6xLe7j/. 
Estava seguindo o que está no site da W3S: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_animate.asp .

Grato!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simples, basta adicionar um position relative na div que você pretende animar, não havendo um atributo position especificado as propriedades top,bottom,left e right passam a ser redundantes por isso sua animação não funcionou.

Segue a solução para o seu problema:

```js
function main() {
  $('.mainBtn').click(function() {
    $("#btn1").animate({
      left: '250px'
    }, 300);
  });

}
$(document).ready(main);
```

```css
.mainBtn {
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  background-color: tomato;
  border-radius: 50%
}
.subBtn {
  top: 120px;
  left: 130px;
  position: relative
}
.listBtn {
  margin: 5px;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  background-color: #C5D1EB;
  border-radius: 50%;
  /* Esse position aqui quem faz tudo funcionar */
  position: relative
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- BOTOES DE NAVEGAÇÃO -->
<div class="menu">
  <!-- BOTOES PRINCIPAIS -->
  <div class="mainBtn">
    <div id="menuBurguer"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- BOTOES SECUNDARIOS -->
  <div class="subBtn">
    <div class="listBtn" id="btn1"></div>
    <div class="listBtn" id="btn2"></div>
    <div class="listBtn" id="btn3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```